# С# (Новичок) 2 строки переписать в 1ну

Tags: c#

С#
Всем привет!) Есть строки **вводимые** пользователем (с **одинак-м кол-м символов и только цифры без пробелов)**

koordShipr1  (например он ввел- **026**)

koordShipr2  (например он ввел- 147)

Нужно их переписать в новую строку koordShipr3 таким образом (**0**1**2**4**6**7)

//Отметил жирными чтобы было понятней)

Comment: Что если строки разной длины или если одна пустая?

Comment: @Monk Строки одинак-й длины без пробелов и содержат только цифры

Comment: @НИК, а в чем цель подобной задачи?

Comment: @sp7 Мне это было нужно для квадрата Полибия (2й метод)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  var str1 = "026";
  var str2 = "147";
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (var index = 0; index < str1.Length; index++)
  {
    builder.Append(str1[index]);
    builder.Append(str2[index]);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ)